# Write each value(list) in a dictionary of lists to a new row

Tags: csv, dictionary, python-3.5

I have a dictionary with 1 key, and multiple list values.

```
{'A-03131': [['Component', 'P-011510', '5'], ['Component', 'P-011319', '1'], ['Component', 'A-03134', '1'], ['Component', 'P-009591', '1'], ['Component', 'P-011509', '1'], ['Component', 'P-011461', '1'], ['Component', 'P-011563', '1'], ['Component', 'A-03094', '2'], ['Component', 'A-03146', '1'], ['Component', 'P-011465', '4']]}
```

I am trying to write each list value to it's own row in a CSV. 
I have currently got this:

```
    with open(file, 'w+') as outfile :
        w = csv.writer(outfile)
        w.writerows(sub_assembly.items())
```

But that is writing the full dictionary to one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `dict.values()` works for my needs.

```
filename = parent_item + '_bom.csv'
file = os.path.join(OUTPATH, filename)
header_row = ['Parent Item ', parent_item]
with open(file, 'w+') as outfile:
    w = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    w.writerow(header_row)
    for value in main_bom.values():
        w.writerows(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically when dealing with excel file,use openpyxl package.
Instead of writing directly iterate through all the rows and insert each list into a row.

using openpyxl,

`wb = openpyxl.Worksheet()`

`ws = wb.active`

`for value in d['A-03131']:
    cell(row = row,column = column).value = value`

`wb.save('assembly.xlsx')`

This is more elegant way of doing excel operations.

Comment: I need my output to be in a csv format for processing further down the line.  I think I've found my solution though and will post once I get it working

Comment: I think you have got the answer.